# Preloading images using PHP and jQuery - Comma separated array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, preload

So I'm building a website that will use a lot of animated GIF's on mouse hover. There will be a lot of images, and I only want to load the images that will be used on any given page. It's using WordPress so I can use the conditional tags to only put out the URL's of the images I need on a certain page.

My problem was how to tell the browser/server which images needed to be preloaded. I decided to add a HTML5 data attribute to the containing element.

For example, I would have a DIV with this PHP in it:

```
<div id="home-container" class="preload" data-preload="<?php echo preloadImages(); ?>"></div>
```

Which would call this function in PHP:

```
function preloadImages() {
    global $post;
    $templateURL = get_template_directory_uri();
    $images = array();

    if( is_page('test') )
        $images[] = "'".$templateURL."/images/gifs-static/button-info-tab-close-off.gif'";
        $images[] = "'".$templateURL."/images/gifs-animated/button-info-tab-close.gif'";
    }

    return implode(", ", $images);
}
```

So the output would be this:

```
<div id="home-container" class="preload" data-preload="'http://example.com/images/gifs-static/button-info-tab-close-off.gif', 'http://example.com/images/gifs-animated/button-info-tab-close.gif'"></div>
```

And then I run this JavaScript:

```
jQuery('.preload').each(function(){

        var images = [
            // Comma separated list
            jQuery(this).data('preload')
        ];

        jQuery(images).each(function() {
            jQuery('<img />').attr('src', this).addClass('preloaded').appendTo('body').hide();
        });
});
```

The problem is that the JavaScript does not like the comma separated list. If I just write in the URLs, it works fine. So is there a better way to pass in those URLs? Or a better way in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the string of URLs by the deliminator commas into an array:

```
    var images = jQuery(this).data('preload').split(',');
```

`jQuery(this).data('preload')` is returning a string, and you can use `.split()` to split that string into an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split

Also you can make your loop run a little faster by using `$.each()`:

```
jQuery('.preload').each(function(){

        var images = [
            // Comma seperated list
            jQuery(this).data('preload')
        ];

        jQuery.each(images, function() {
            jQuery('<img />').attr('src', this).addClass('preloaded').appendTo('body').hide();
        });
});
```

Note that you shouldn't have anything other than the commas that separate the different urls in the `data-attribute`:

```
<div id="home-container" class="preload" data-preload="http://example.com/images/gifs-static/button-info-tab-close-off.gif,http://example.com/images/gifs-animated/button-info-tab-close.gif"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put the list directly in a Js array ?

Something like :

```
<script>
    var aPreloadImages = <?php echo preloadImages(); ?>;

    for (index in aPreloadImages) {
        jQuery('<img />').attr('src', aPreloadImages[index]).addClass('preloaded').appendTo('body').hide();
    }
</script>
```

And your PHP code :

```
function preloadImages() {
    global $post;
    $templateURL = get_template_directory_uri();
    $images = array();

    if( is_page('test') )
        $images[] = "'".$templateURL."/images/gifs-static/button-info-tab-close-off.gif'";
        $images[] = "'".$templateURL."/images/gifs-animated/button-info-tab-close.gif'";
    }

    return json_encode($images);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to keep my JS separate from my HTML. Is there a way to keep it separate?

Comment: Well then I think the answer from @Jasper is better appropriate for your need.

Comment: This is definitely the most straightforward approach. Writing to HTML, rendering, then reading from the DOM is two stages more indirect. +1 @cx42net.

Comment: @Drew Baker This IS the way to keep it separate!

Answer (score 1):

Make your php return the data to the element as an actual array, wrapped in `[]`. Then, when you pull it from the data attribute using the .data() method, jquery will convert it into a real array.

div

```
<div class="preload" data-preload='["foo.jpg","bar.jpg","foobar.gif","barfoo.png"]'></div>
```

code

```
var images = jQuery(this).data('preload');
```